# order by foreign key in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a tables `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has one `Bar`. When I query `Foo`, how can I order it by a date column in the `Bar` table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Foo.find(:all,:joins=>:boo, :order=>'bars.created_at DESC' )
```

Comment: Fixed it + use :joins if u don't care for eager loading boo fields

Comment: I only vote down because if boo is a huge table, you pull all the data from the boo record to the object.  Heavy weight traffic for a sort

Comment: If you're joining to a huge table and are concerned about the performance of your load operation, you could add a "sort_order" column to Foo, and make Bar responsible for updating it's foo.sort_order whenever the relevant date column is updated. I guess the question is if you want to optimize for writing or reading

Comment: actually the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763012/order-by-foreign-key-in-activerecord-without-a-join?lq=1 has a good middle ground for not loading all of the joined record's attributes

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the ActiveRecord Query Interface page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Note that sometimes a prefix is added to the table name so you may need to do something like:

```
Foo.all(:joins => :bar, :order => Bar.table_name + '.created_at')
```