# Order by foreign key in activerecord: without a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I want to expand this question. 
[order by foreign key in activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586848/order-by-foreign-key-in-activerecord)

I'm trying to order a set of records based on a value in a really large table.
When I use join, it brings all the "other" records data into the objects.. As join should..

```
#table users  30+ columns
#table bids  5 columns
record = Bid.find(:all,:joins=>:users, :order=>'users.ranking DESC' ).first
```

Now record holds 35 fields..

Is there a way to do this without the join?

Here's my thinking..
With the join I get this query

```
SELECT * FROM "bids" 
left join users on runner_id = users.id  
ORDER BY ranking LIMIT 1
```

Now I can add a select to the code so I don't get the full user table, but putting a select in a scope is dangerous IMHO.

When I write sql by hand.

```
SELECT * FROM bids 
order by (select users.ranking from users where users.id = runner_id) DESC
limit 1
```

I believe this is a faster query, based on the "explain" it seems simpler.
More important than speed though is that the second method doesn't have the 30 extra fields.
If I build in a custom select inside the scope, it could explode other searches on the object if they too have custom selects (there can be only one)

Comment: What I eventually settled on. scope :order_by_ranking, -> { order('(select ranking from users where users.id = runner_id) DESC')  }

Comment: EXPLAIN shows you the query plan that will be used, it doesn't tell you anything about performance: It could be a horrible query plan.... Use EXPLAIN ANALYZE for information about performance and memory usage.

Comment: Don't current versions of rails default the select to bids.* in this case? Your second query looks like it would have to run the subquery for each row which would be slow

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to achieve in active record writing is something along

`SELECT b.* from bids b inner join users u on u.id=b.user_id order by u.ranking desc`

In active record i would write such as:
`Bids.joins("inner join users u on bids.user_id=u.id").order("u.ranking desc")`

I think it's the only to make a join without fetching all attributes from the user models.

Comment: +1 This is what I'm going to use.. but it sort of doesn't answer the question because I specifically said without join.  I'll leave the question open only for that reason.